# Expectation of complex random variable

Tags: pr.probability, cv.complex-variables

I am researching frequency offset estimation and ended up reading a paper "Cramer-Rao Lower Bound on Frequency Offset Estimation Error in OFDM Systems With Timing Error Feedback Compensation" and trying to verify the proof of the bound for this specific case. The last step of the proof is the computation of the integral

$\mathbb{E}\left[\dfrac{\partial^2 \Lambda(\mathbf{r}|\Omega)}{\partial^2\Omega}\right] = c_5\sum_{n \in I}\iint \Re\left[e^{-j2\pi\Omega}\alpha\beta\right]\text{exp}(-\dfrac{|\alpha|^2 - 2\rho\Re(e^{-j2\pi\Omega}\alpha\beta^*) + |\beta|^2}{(\sigma_s^2 + \sigma_w^2)(1-\rho^2)}) \,d\alpha\,d\beta$

where integration is preformed over the complex plane, i.e. α and β are complex. How to compute such an integral in practice? Any help is appriciated. As the integrand is independent of $n$, it should also be mentioned that $|I| = L$. We are trying to extend this formula so the explicit computation is important.

Comment: It appears that an appropriate change of variables (to diagonalise the quadratic form inside the exponential) will convert this to a gaussian integral $\int_{\mathbb{R}^4}x^TAx\exp(-\|x\|^2)dx=\text{trace}(A)\pi^2/2$.  If you need more details about how to do the diagonalisation it will probably be better to ask at math.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thank you for your comment! It helped me to find the right path and now my result matches the paper. I will probably answer my own question with the calculations when I have written them up. Do you have a reference for the formula $\int_{\mathbb{R}^4}x^TAx\exp(-\|x\|^2)dx=\text{trace}(A)\pi^2/2$? It seems to hold but I couldn't find a reference. @NeilStrickland

Comment: I don't know a reference for that, but it follows easily from $\int_{\mathbb{R}}xe^{-x^2}dx=0$ (clear from oddness) and $\int_{\mathbb{R}}x^2e^{-x^2}dx=\sqrt{\pi}/2$ (square it and convert to polar coordinates) and $\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-x^2}dx=\sqrt{\pi}$.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This gives the details for calculating the integral in the paper

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}\left[\dfrac{\partial^2 \Lambda(\mathbf{r}|\Omega)}{\partial^2\Omega}\right] = c_5\sum_{n \in I}\iint\Re\left[e^{-j2\pi\Omega}\alpha\beta^*\right]\text{exp}(-\dfrac{|\alpha|^2 - 2\rho\Re(e^{-j2\pi\Omega}\alpha\beta^*) + |\beta|^2}{(\sigma_s^2 + \sigma_w^2)(1-\rho^2)}) \,d\alpha\,d\beta
\end{align*}
where $|I| = L$ and
\begin{align*}
c_5 = -\dfrac{8\rho}{(\sigma_s^2 + \sigma_w^2)^3(1-\rho^2)^2}.
\end{align*}

First of all, the integrand doesn't depend on $n$ so we are left with a constant in front of the integrals

\begin{align*}
c_5L\iint \Re\left[e^{-j2\pi\Omega}\alpha\beta^*\right]\text{exp}(-\dfrac{|\alpha|^2 - 2\rho\Re(e^{-j2\pi\Omega}\alpha\beta^*) + |\beta|^2}{(\sigma_s^2 + \sigma_w^2)(1-\rho^2)}) \,d\alpha\,d\beta
\end{align*}

The complex integral can be thought as four real integrals when the complex numbers are split into the real and imaginary parts

\begin{align*}
&c_5L\int_\mathbb{C} \int_\mathbb{C} \Re\left[e^{-j2\pi\Omega}\alpha\beta^*\right]\text{exp}(-\dfrac{|\alpha|^2 - 2\rho\Re(e^{-j2\pi\Omega}\alpha\beta^*) + |\beta|^2}{(\sigma_s^2 + \sigma_w^2)(1-\rho^2)}) \,d\alpha\,d\beta = \\ &c_5L \int_\mathbb{R} \int_\mathbb{R} \int_\mathbb{R} \int_\mathbb{R} \Re\left[e^{-j2\pi\Omega}(\alpha_{r} + i\alpha_{i})(\beta_{r} - i\beta_{i})\right]\text{exp}(-\dfrac{\alpha_{r}^2 + \alpha_{i}^2 - 2\rho\Re\left[e^{-j2\pi\Omega}(\alpha_{r} + i\alpha_{i})(\beta_{r} - i\beta_{i})\right] + \beta_{r}^2 + \beta_{i}^2}{(\sigma_s^2 + \sigma_w^2)(1-\rho^2)}) \,d\alpha_{r}\,d\alpha_{i}\,d\beta_{r}\,d\beta_{i}
\end{align*}

Consider first the real part
\begin{align*}
&\Re\left[e^{-j2\pi\Omega}(\alpha_{r} + i\alpha_{i})(\beta_{r} - i\beta_{i})\right] = \Re\left[e^{-j2\pi\Omega}(\alpha_r\beta_r + i\alpha_i\beta_r - i\alpha_r\beta_i + \alpha_i\beta_i)\right] = \\ &\Re\left[e^{-j2\pi\Omega}(\alpha_r\beta_r + \alpha_i\beta_i) + e^{-j2\pi\Omega + j\frac{\pi}{2}}(\alpha_i\beta_r - \alpha_r\beta_i)\right]  = \\ &\cos(-2\pi\Omega)(\alpha_r\beta_r + \alpha_i\beta_i) + \cos(-2\pi\Omega + \frac{\pi}{2})(\alpha_i\beta_r - \alpha_r\beta_i) = \\ &\cos(2\pi\Omega)(\alpha_r\beta_r + \alpha_i\beta_i) + \sin(2\pi\Omega)(\alpha_i\beta_r - \alpha_r\beta_i)
\end{align*}
Denote $\xi = \cos(2\pi\Omega)$ and $\psi = \sin(2\pi\Omega)$
and we get
\begin{align*}
    &\Re\left[e^{-j2\pi\Omega}(\alpha_{r} + i\alpha_{i})(\beta_{r} - i\beta_{i})\right] = \xi(\alpha_r\beta_r + \alpha_i\beta_i) + \psi(\alpha_i\beta_r - \alpha_r\beta_i)
\end{align*}
Moreover denote $\lambda = -2\rho\xi$ and $\mu = -2\rho\psi$.
Now we can write the integral as

\begin{align*}
&c_5L \int_\mathbb{R} \int_\mathbb{R} \int_\mathbb{R} \int_\mathbb{R} \Re\left[e^{-j2\pi\Omega}(\alpha_{r} + i\alpha_{i})(\beta_{r} - i\beta_{i})\right]\text{exp}(-\dfrac{\alpha_{r}^2 + \alpha_{i}^2 - 2\rho\Re\left[e^{-j2\pi\Omega}(\alpha_{r} + i\alpha_{i})(\beta_{r} - i\beta_{i})\right] + \beta_{r}^2 + \beta_{i}^2}{(\sigma_s^2 + \sigma_w^2)(1-\rho^2)}) \,d\alpha_{r}\,d\alpha_{i}\,d\beta_{r}\,d\beta_{i} = \\ &c_5L \int_\mathbb{R} \int_\mathbb{R} \int_\mathbb{R} \int_\mathbb{R} \left(\xi(\alpha_r\beta_r + \alpha_i\beta_i) + \psi(\alpha_i\beta_r - \alpha_r\beta_i)\right)\text{exp}(-\dfrac{\alpha_r^2 + \alpha_i^2 - 2\rho\xi(\alpha_r\beta_r + \alpha_i\beta_i) - 2\rho\psi(\alpha_i\beta_r - \alpha_r\beta_i) + \beta_r^2 + \beta_i^2}{(\sigma_s^2 + \sigma_w^2)(1-\rho^2)}\,d\alpha_{r}\,d\alpha_{i}\,d\beta_{r}\,d\beta_{i}
\end{align*}

Denote by $\delta = \dfrac{1}{(\sigma_s^2 + \sigma_w^2)(1-\rho^2)}$ and we get

\begin{align*}
    &c_5L \int_\mathbb{R} \int_\mathbb{R} \int_\mathbb{R} \int_\mathbb{R} \left(\xi(\alpha_r\beta_r + \alpha_i\beta_i) + \psi(\alpha_i\beta_r - \alpha_r\beta_i)\right)\text{exp}(-\delta(\alpha_r^2 + \alpha_i^2  - 2\rho\xi(\alpha_r\beta_r + \alpha_i\beta_i) - 2\rho\psi(\alpha_i\beta_r - \alpha_r\beta_i) + \beta_r^2 + \beta_i^2))\,d\alpha_{r}\,d\alpha_{i}\,d\beta_{r}\,d\beta_{i}
\end{align*}

Now we can interpret the quadratic forms with symmetric matrices
as follows:
\begin{align*}
    \xi(\alpha_r\beta_r + \alpha_i\beta_i) + \psi(\alpha_i\beta_r - \alpha_r\beta_i) = \begin{pmatrix} \alpha_r & \alpha_i & \beta_r & \beta_i \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}  0 & 0 & \frac{\xi}{2} & -\frac{\psi}{2} \\ 0 & 0 & \frac{\psi}{2} & \frac{\xi}{2} \\
    \frac{\xi}{2} & \frac{\psi}{2} & 0 & 0 \\ -\frac{\psi}{2} & \frac{\xi}{2} & 0 & 0
    \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} \alpha_r \\ \alpha_i \\ \beta_r \\ \beta_i \end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
    \alpha_r^2 + \alpha_i^2 + \beta_r^2 + \beta_i^2 = \begin{pmatrix} \alpha_r & \alpha_i & \beta_r & \beta_i \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} \alpha_r \\ \alpha_i \\ \beta_r \\ \beta_i \end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}

Denote by $S = \begin{pmatrix}  0 & 0 & \frac{\xi}{2} & -\frac{\psi}{2} \\ 0 & 0 & \frac{\psi}{2} & \frac{\xi}{2} \\
    \frac{\xi}{2} & \frac{\psi}{2} & 0 & 0 \\ -\frac{\psi}{2} & \frac{\xi}{2} & 0 & 0
    \end{pmatrix}$ and with $B = \delta(-2\rho S + I)$.
Now the integral becomes

\begin{align*}
    &c_5L \int_\mathbb{R} \int_\mathbb{R} \int_\mathbb{R} \int_\mathbb{R} \left(\xi(\alpha_r\beta_r + \alpha_i\beta_i) + \psi(\alpha_i\beta_r - \alpha_r\beta_i)\right)\text{exp}(-\delta(\alpha_r^2 + \alpha_i^2 - 2\rho\xi(\alpha_r\beta_r + \alpha_i\beta_i) - 2\rho\psi(\alpha_i\beta_r - \alpha_r\beta_i) + \beta_r^2 + \beta_i^2))\,d\alpha_{r}\,d\alpha_{i}\,d\beta_{r}\,d\beta_{i} = \\
    &c_5L \int_{\mathbb{R}^4} xSx^Te^{-xBx^T}\,dx
\end{align*}

Since $B$ is a symmetric matrix, it can be diagonalized with an orthogonal matrix. Calculate the eigenvalues and eigenvectors with Mathematica and the diagonalization becomes: $B = P^TDP$, where
\begin{align*}
&D = \delta\begin{pmatrix} 1-\sqrt{\rho^2\xi^2 + \rho^2\psi^2} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1-\sqrt{\rho^2\xi^2 + \rho^2\psi^2} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1+\sqrt{\rho^2\xi^2 + \rho^2\psi^2} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1+\sqrt{\rho^2\xi^2 + \rho^2\psi^2}
\end{pmatrix} \\
&P = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}\rho(\xi^2 + \psi^2)}\begin{pmatrix}
-\psi\sqrt{\rho^2(\xi^2+\psi^2)} & \xi\sqrt{\rho^2(\xi^2+\psi^2)} & 0 & \rho(\xi^2 + \psi^2) \\
\xi\sqrt{\rho^2(\xi^2+\psi^2)} & \psi\sqrt{\rho^2(\xi^2+\psi^2)} & \rho(\xi^2 + \psi^2) & 0 \\
\psi\sqrt{\rho^2(\xi^2+\psi^2)} & -\xi\sqrt{\rho^2(\xi^2+\psi^2)} & 0 & \rho(\xi^2 + \psi^2) \\
-\xi\sqrt{\rho^2(\xi^2+\psi^2)} & -\psi\sqrt{\rho^2(\xi^2+\psi^2)} & \rho(\xi^2 + \psi^2) & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
Since $P$ is orthogonal, we have $PP^T = P^TP= I$. Also the diagonal matrix $D$ can be split into a product of two diagonal matrices with square root entries $D = \sqrt{D}\sqrt{D}$. A little bit of algebra yields $B = P^TDP = P^T\sqrt{D}\sqrt{D}P \implies \sqrt{D}^{-1}PBP^T\sqrt{D}^{-1} = I$. Now this means that if in the integral we substitute $x\sqrt{D}^{-1}P$ in place of $x$, we will get a Gaussian integral:
\begin{align*}
    &c_5L \int_{\mathbb{R}^4} xSx^Te^{-xBx^T}\,dx = c_5L\int_{\mathbb{R}^4} x\sqrt{D}^{-1}PS(x\sqrt{D}^{-1}P)^Te^{-x\sqrt{D}^{-1}PB(x\sqrt{D}^{-1}P)^T}|\det(\sqrt{D}^{-1}P)|\,dx = \\ &c_5L\int_{\mathbb{R}^4} x\sqrt{D}^{-1}PSP^T\sqrt{D}^{-1}x^Te^{-x(\sqrt{D}^{-1}PBP^T\sqrt{D}^{-1})x^T}|\det(\sqrt{D}^{-1}P)|\,dx = c_5L|\det(\sqrt{D}^{-1}P)|\int_{\mathbb{R}^4}xAx^Te^{-xx^T}\,dx
\end{align*}
And here we denoted $A = \sqrt{D}^{-1}PSP^T\sqrt{D}^{-1} = \\ \dfrac{\sqrt{\rho^2(\xi^2 + \psi^2)}}{2\delta\rho} \begin{pmatrix} \dfrac{1}{1 - \sqrt{\rho^2(\xi^2 + \psi^2)}} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \dfrac{1}{1 - \sqrt{\rho^2(\xi^2 + \psi^2)}} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \dfrac{1}{1 + \sqrt{\rho^2(\xi^2 + \psi^2)}} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \dfrac{1}{1 + \sqrt{\rho^2(\xi^2 + \psi^2)}}
\end{pmatrix}$. \

First prove that $\int_{\mathbb{R}^4}xAx^Te^{-xx^T}\,dx = \operatorname{Tr}(A)\dfrac{\pi^2}{2}$.

Denote the elements of matrix $A$ by $a_{ij}$, where $i,j \in \{1,2,3,4\}$. Open the matrix product and by linearity of integration
\begin{align*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^4}xAx^Te^{-xx^T}\,dx =  \sum_{i=1}^4\sum_{j=1}^4\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}x_ia_{ij}x_je^{-(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2)}\,dx_1\,dx_2\,dx_3\,dx_4
\end{align*}
Analyze the terms that are summed:
If $i \neq j$, we have

\begin{align*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}}x_ia_{ij}x_je^{-(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2)}\,dx_i = 0
\end{align*}
by oddity of $x_ie^{-x_i^2}$.
And this means that
\begin{align*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}x_ia_{ij}x_je^{-(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2)}\,dx_1\,dx_2\,dx_3\,dx_4 = 0
\end{align*}
If $i = j$, we have. Without loss of generality, assume that $i=1$ (just rename the variables and order the integrals accordingly).
\begin{align*}
    &\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}a_{11}x_1^2e^{-(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2)}\,dx_1\,dx_2\,dx_3\,dx_4 = \\
    &a_{11}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}x_1^2e^{-(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2)}\,dx_1\,dx_2\,dx_3\,dx_4 = \\
    &a_{11}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-(x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2)} \int_{\mathbb{R}} x_1^2e^{-x_1^2} \,dx_1\,dx_2\,dx_3\,dx_4 = \\
    &a_{11}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-(x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2)} \dfrac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \,dx_2\,dx_3\,dx_4 = a_{11}\dfrac{\pi^2}{2}.
\end{align*}
We take here as facts that $\int_{\mathbb{R}}x^2e^{-x^2} = \dfrac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$ and $\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-x^2} = \sqrt{\pi}$.

Now the sum becomes
\begin{align*}
&\sum_{i=1}^4\sum_{j=1}^4\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}x_ia_{ij}x_je^{-(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2)}\,dx_1\,dx_2\,dx_3\,dx_4 = \sum_{i=1}^4\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}x_ia_{ii}x_ie^{-(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2)}\,dx_1\,dx_2\,dx_3\,dx_4 = \\ &(a_{11} + a_{22} + a_{33} + a_{44})\dfrac{\pi^2}{2} = \operatorname{Tr}(A)\dfrac{\pi^2}{2}
\end{align*}

Now it follows that $\int_{\mathbb{R}^4}xAx^Te^{-xx^T}\,dx = \operatorname{Tr}(A)\dfrac{\pi^2}{2} = -\dfrac{\pi^2\rho(\xi^2 + \psi^2)}{\delta(-1 + \rho^2(\xi^2 + \psi^2))}$

Now the value of the actual integral can be evaluated by plugging constants in

\begin{align*}
    &c_5L|\det(\sqrt{D}^{-1}P)|\int_{\mathbb{R}^4}xAx^Te^{-xx^T}\,dx = c_5L|\det(\sqrt{D}^{-1}P)|\left(-\dfrac{\pi^2\rho(\xi^2 + \psi^2)}{\delta(-1 + \rho^2(\xi^2 + \psi^2))}\right) = \\
    &c_5L\bigg | -\dfrac{1}{\delta^2(-1+\rho^2(\xi^2+\psi^2))} \bigg |\left(-\dfrac{\pi^2\rho(\xi^2 + \psi^2)}{\delta(-1 + \rho^2(\xi^2 + \psi^2))}\right)
\end{align*}

Notice that $\xi^2 + \psi^2 = \cos^2(2\pi\Omega) + \sin^2(2\pi\Omega) = 1$.

\begin{align*}
    -c_5L\dfrac{\pi^2\rho}{\delta^3\text{Sign}[-1 + \rho^2](-1+\rho^2)^2}
\end{align*}
As $\rho = \dfrac{SNR}{SNR + 1} \implies \text{Sign}[-1 + \rho^2] = -1$. Substitute the definition of $c_5$ also
\begin{align*}
-&\dfrac{8\rho L}{(\sigma_s^2+\sigma_w^2)^3(1-\rho^2)^2}\dfrac{\pi^2\rho}{\delta^3(-1+\rho^2)^2} = \\
&-\dfrac{8\rho^2\pi^2L}{(\sigma_s^2+\sigma_w^2)^3(1-\rho^2)^4\delta^3}
\end{align*}
Plug in the definition of $\delta$ and we have verified the result in the paper
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}\left[\dfrac{\partial^2 \Lambda(\mathbf{r}|\Omega)}{\partial^2\Omega}\right] = -\dfrac{8\pi^2\rho^2L}{1-\rho^2} 
\end{align*}